# Get all tasks of a process instance in activiti 7

Tags: activiti

I am using Activiti 7.1.24 in Spring boot for workflow controls

when a process instance is started, I would like to check all the tasks defined in BPMN file. below is the code I used to list them.

```
taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).list();
```

unfortunately, the list method return only the first task of the process instance.

my question is, how to get other tasks from query, did I do anything incorrectly? if not how can I get all the tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of task's

```
 List<Task> taskInstances = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).active().list();
```

Best Regards

Comment: It gives the same outcome - the first task in the process instance.